# Count then group 2 columns from SQL Table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I'm using a table structure like this:

```
departure | destination | Type    | Pilot
EDDK        EDDM          flight    name
EDDK        EDDI          flight    name
EDDI        EDDK          flight    name
EDDK        EDDP          flight    name
EDDM        EDDK          flight    name
EDDF        EDDK          flight    name
EDDF        EDDI          flight    name

and so on...
```

now I'm using a codeigniter sql query like this:

```
$query = $this->db->select('departure, COUNT(departure) as zaehler', False)
                    ->from('tablename')
                    ->where('Pilot', $user)
                    ->where('Type', 'flight')
                    ->group_by('departure')
                    ->order_by('zaehler', 'DESC')
                    ->get();

return $query->result();
```

this results in an array as expected:

```
Array
(
   [0] => stdClass Object
      (
        [departure] => EDDK
        [zaehler] => 3
     )

   [1] => stdClass Object
      (
        [departure] => EDDF
        [zaehler] => 2
      )

   [2] => stdClass Object
      (
        [departure] => EDDM
        [zaehler] => 1
      )
   [3] => stdClass Object
      (
        [departure] => EDDI
        [zaehler] => 1
      )
```

I'm also using the same query for "destinations".
Is it possible to get the result of these 2 queries in just one?
So the result looks like this?

```
Array
  (
   [0] => EDDK
      (
        [departure] => 3
        [destination] => 3
     )

   [1] => EDDF
      (
        [departure] => 2
        [destination] => 0
      )

   [2] => EDDM
      (
        [departure] => 1
        [destination] => 1
      )
   [3] => EDDI
      (
        [departure] => 1
        [destination] => 2
      )
   [4] => EDDP
      (
        [departure] => 0
        [destination] => 1
      )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll leave it to you to translate this to your php-format, but the general form of the query for this is like this:

```
SELECT Departure, DepCnt, DesCnt FROM
(SELECT Departure, COUNT(Departure) AS DepCnt FROM T
GROUP BY Departure)
INNER JOIN
(SELECT Destination, COUNT(Destination) AS DesCnt FROM T
GROUP BY Destination)
ON Departure = Destination
```

As mentioned in the comment, above solution will omit locations when it has either no departures or no destinations. The following modification deals with this.

```
SELECT Loc, COALESCE(DepCnt,0), COALESCE(DesCnt,0) FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT Departure AS Loc FROM T
UNION
SELECT DISTINCT Destination FROM T)
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT Departure, COUNT(Departure) AS DepCnt FROM T
GROUP BY Departure) ON Departure = Loc
LEFT OUTER JOIN
(SELECT Destination, COUNT(Destination) AS DesCnt FROM T
GROUP BY Destination) ON Destination = Loc
```

Comment: this does not count when either departure or destination is 0

Comment: @TNT_Larsn you're right. I added an extra solution that should deal with that.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sqlQuery = "SELECT distinct departure,";
$sqlQuery .= "  (SELECT count(*) FROM tablename b WHERE b.departure = a.departure) as 'departure',";
$sqlQuery .= "  (SELECT count(*) FROM tablename b WHERE b.destination = a.destination) as 'destination'";
$sqlQuery .= "FROM tablename a ";

$query = $this->db->query($sqlQuery);

return $query->result();
```

This will count all departures and destinations for each "destination". You can feel free to add the "WHERE" syntax or improve in your own way

Comment: I think applying distinct to a subquery should cause a syntax error.

Comment: I did a subquery with distinct a secs ago: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/39f41/19 , what error do you mean?